# How to write a system of stochastic differential equations (SDE) mathematically correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

**Aim**

I am trying to write down a system of stochastic differential equations, however, since I lack a background in mathematics I am not sure how to do this.

Let's say I have the following system of ordinary differential equations, a simple Lotka Volterra Model:

$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x = \alpha x - \beta x y \\ 
\dot y = \delta x y - \gamma y
\end{array}
\right.$$

with initial values for x = 10 and y = 10.

The parameter values for alpha, beta, delta and gamma are 1.1, 0.4, 0.1 and 0.4 respectively (mimicking this [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)).

In order to rewrite it to a system of stochastic differential equations, I rewrote the ODE system like this:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{d x}{d t}=\alpha x -\beta xy \\ 
\frac{d y}{d t}=\delta xy - \gamma y \\
\frac{d \alpha }{d t}= 0 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

In this way, I am able to let parameter $\alpha$ follow a random walk with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 0.01$ (normal distribution).

**Attempt**

I thought a system of SDEs has the following format:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\ dX(t) = b(X(t))dt + B(X(t))dW(t) \\ 
\ X(0) = x_0 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

However, I am not sure how to write down this ODE model as an SDE model with random walk.

**Question**

How do I write down this system of stochastic differential equations mathematically correct?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of $\delta$ as parameter and differential operator. I altered it in the second example. I am not sure how to answer the second question though: it is a random walk, by which at each time step in a simulation, a random number from a distribution ($\mu = 0, \sigma = 0.01$) is added to $\alpha$. I set $\alpha = 0$ in the ODE to be able to put the random walk alone on $\alpha$ and not on the entire first equations of the system.

Comment: As far as I understand, $\alpha$ is additive white Gaussian noise.

Comment: This is not rigorous, but think in terms of $\mathrm d w = \alpha \,\mathrm d t$.

Comment: You want $dα=σ\,dW$, or possibly $dα=σα\,dW$ or similar. If you want to randomize also the other parameters, you need to decide if they all follow the same random influence $W$, or if there will be a vector of Wiener walks involved.

Comment: Take a look at chapter 1 of [Evans's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=VYoCAQAAQBAJ).

Comment: @LutzL You're assuming $\alpha$ is a Wiener process or a geometric Brownian motion, when the OP mentioned it was AWGN.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo : That was indeed said, but it does not make sense. $α$ is a coefficient that is changed from being constant to something randomly variable. For the system to stay a sensible differential equation, it should be a randomly evolving continuous function, as provided by a scaled Brownian motion. One might add the assumption that it has to stay positive, thus the proposal of a geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: @LutzL : If I understand the comments correctly, I can replace $\frac{d \alpha }{d t}= 0$ by $\frac{d \alpha }{d t}= \sigma dW$ in the example below to transform the system of ODEs into a system of SDEs? In that way, the SDE is written mathematically correct?

Comment: The SDE $dα =σdW$ is the limit of the discretization $α(t+dt)-α(t)=σz(t)\sqrt{dt}$ where $z(t)\sim N(0,1)$ has a standard normal distribution. If you divide that by $dt$ and consider the limit, the right side is almost always infinitely large. Please look up Ito integrals and the integral formulation of SDE, the differential form means the same, it is a symbolic abbreviation for that.